# How to keep the unicode comma in Perl 5?

Tags: perl

The $line contains unicode comma.

```
use strict;
use utf8;

my $line = "Spy，qqq，Iwm";

$line =~ s/[^a-zA-Z u002cu002e]+//g;
print $line."\n";
```

When i run it, i get
$ perl 1.pl

SpyqqqIwm

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `u002c` should be `\x{002c}` or `\x2c` or `,`

Comment: `u002e` should be `\x{002e}` or `\x2e` or `.`

Comment: Note that to print unicode characters properly you will either need to encode it to your terminal's encoding (most likely UTF-8) or set an encoding layer on STDOUT (`use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)'` or `-CS` on the commandline).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character in question is U+FF0C FULLWIDTH COMMA

You can use it literally.

```
s/[^a-zA-Z ,，.]+//g
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the following in double-quoted and regex literals:

```
\N{U+FF0C}
\N{FULLWIDTH COMMA}
\x{FF0C}
```

For example,

```
s/[^a-zA-Z ,\N{U+FF0C}.]+//g
```

Comment: Not easy, for period, 4 of them, U+3002 。  e3 80 82 IDEO­GRAPHIC FULL STOP IDEOGRAPHIC PERIOD
U+FE52 ﹒  ef b9 92 SMALL FULL STOP SMALL PERIOD
U+FF0E ．  ef bc 8e FULLWIDTH FULL STOP FULLWIDTH PERIOD
U+FF61 ｡  ef bd a1 HALFWIDTH IDEO­GRAPHIC FULL STOP HALFWIDTH IDEOGRAPHIC PERIOD